# Website received malicious customers : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, newsletter

Website receiving the customers with `emails, names, and addresses` contains **only strings of numerical values** followed by the **@qq.com/@843145.com** domain.

We have received every day more than 10 customers and newsletters subscription. See below screenshots. 
[image]

Please suggest how to avoid these type of issue?

Comment: Captcha is the best solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Captcha in your website forms.

Magento provides native captcha for:

- Customer Registration
- Customer Login
- Customer Forgot Password
- Checkout as Guest
- Register during Checkout
- Contact Form

You can easily enable captcha from **Stores > Configuration > Customers (Customer Configuration) > Captcha** section.

Apart from that, you can find extensions if you want to use Google ReCaptcha on your website.

Below are some extension links:

- https://amasty.com/google-invisible-recaptcha-for-magento-2.html